# how to get data-id and pass it into function?

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<a class="bookmarkit" href="#modalBookmark" data-toggle="modal" role="button" data-id="${image?.id}">Bookmark</a>

$('#modalBookmark').on('shown', function(){

  getBookmarks( userId, $(this).data('id'));


});

$('.btn-add-list').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var bookmarkName = $('.des-bookmark-new input[name="list"]').val();
  console.log(bookmarkName);
  var bookmark = { ownerId: userId, name: bookmarkName };
  addBookmark( bookmark );

});

$('.des-bookmark-list-wrapper').on('click', '.des-bookmark-link', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('here - add bookmark group');
  addBookmarkItem( $(this), $(this).data('id'), $(this).parent().attr('data-bookmark-id') );
});
```

it will be dynamic id that would be passed to jquery bookmark function to get bookmark value, show count after choosing the bookmark group, etc. 
The problem is that $(this).data('id') is not defined.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean its not defined - I see the attribute in the tag?

Comment: Is `$(this).parent().attr('data-bookmark-id')` not defined also? Without seeing the entire html these click functions are targeting can't really help get your traversal on point.

Comment: $('#modalBookmark') this doe not select the a tag in your code, it will select the element with id="modalBookmark" not href = "#modalBookmark" i.e. the a tags target, does that have a data-id on it?

Comment: Have you added `#modalBookmark` id in `anchor` tag?
That are using in jQuery `$('#modalBookmark').on('shown', function(){..});`

Comment: @d3c0y yes $(this).parent().attr('data-bookmark-id') returns number as it is supposed to get value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open `modal` box, this function target `modal` div not an  anchor `opener` link

```
$('#modalBookmark').on('shown', function(){
   getBookmarks( userId, $(this).data('id'));
})
```

You should try this way

```
<a class="bookmarkit" href="#modalBookmark" data-toggle="modal" role="button" data-id="${image?.id}">Bookmark</a>
```

And use current anchor selector with `shown` event

```
$('#modalBookmark').on('shown', function(){

  getBookmarks( userId, $(".bookmarkit").data('id'));

});
```

OR with `click` event

```
$(".bookmarkit").on('click', function(){
   getBookmarks( userId, $(this).data('id'));
})
```

hope it would work

Comment: @kittymeows, bootstreap `modal` will be worked fine due to `data-toggle="modal"` attribute, but this section`$('#modalBookmark').on('shown', function(){ getBookmarks( userId, $(this).data('id'));})` will execute when you will add right selector in `anchor` tag

Comment: ah, i see. ok i tried your example, but it returned undefined. hmm.

Comment: @kittymeows, i have modified answer, please try this way

Comment: yeah i have already modified it and it does return something, but problem is PUT. PUT ...api/bookmarks/1027?item=6827&ownerId=7 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
    $(this).attr('data-id')

Comment: Ya try this kitty, replace 
`addBookmarkItem( $(this), $(this).data('id'), $(this).parent().attr('data-bookmark-id') );` 
with `addBookmarkItem( $(this), $(this).attr('data-id'), $(this).parent().attr('data-bookmark-id') );`